# c#/asp.net - How to catch "System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext, httprequest

In my asp.net/c# project I am using the iTextsharp dll to read the text from many pdf documents, but sometimes I get this error

System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out.

But the code that does it is:

```
    public static bool does_pdf_have_keyword(string keyword, string pdf_src) 
    {
        try
        {
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf_src);
            string currentText;
            int count = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
            for (int page = 1; page <= count; page++)
            {
                ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
                currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);
                if (currentText.IndexOf(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != -1) return true;
            }
            pdfReader.Close();
            return false;
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So why does the page go into an unhandled exception when it's in a try catch and the catch is supposed to catch everything?

Comment: How are you running this?  In Visual Studio?

Comment: post a stacktrace please

Comment: no, it's a webpart thats run in sharepoint 2010 (so on the server side), also how can I get a stacktrace of this, if the page is going into an unhandled error state? I can get the stack trace if I am able to catch the error.

Comment: I suspect this isn't even the part of the code trowing that exception since PdfReader(string filename) reads from a file and not an url. my guess is that this operation takes too long and the http request times out.

Comment: @christian, no it can read from a path to a pdf as well, because it works most of the time, but sometimes I get this unhandled error of request timing out.

Comment: how long does it take for this webpart to load on average?

Comment: @omega To get the stack trace in SharePoint: http://blog-sharepoint.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/sharepoint-webconfig-how-to-show-full.html

Comment: if you mean to run the function for each pdf, on average about 10 seconds to go through around 174 pdf files, but when it takes longer than that, then I get that error.

Answer (score 5):

I think the reason your `try` is not catching this exception is that the exception you're getting is not thrown from your code per se, but from the server.

Think about it this way:

- Your code is running fine, it's just taking a long time.
- The server monitors how long the request is taking, kills the request and throws an exception.

So your code doesn't actually throw that exception.

Now, if you want to find out about it or log it, you can use the `Application_Error` method in your `Global.asax` file (assuming you have access to it, I'm not sure how that works with SharePoint).

For example, in one of my web projects, I wanted to log all errors, even ones that weren't caught. So what I do is something like this:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    //Log ALL uncaught exceptions
    Exception exc = Server.GetLastError();
    if (exc is HttpUnhandledException) {
        exc = Context.Error.InnerException;
    }
    //Log error here
}
```

I'm not sure there's much you can do with it other than log it. I don't know where in the page life cycle this occurs so I'm not sure if you could do something like get the current HTTP request object and redirect the user.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I can redirect the user, but I don't understand how to detect when there is a request time out (before the page goes into an error screen).

Comment: Like I said, the page timeout is external to your code. I'm not exactly sure what code throws the Exception (i.e. where you would put your `try`) but this will let you log it and figure that out. Or perhaps redirect the user to another page after the error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

You are catching the exception, but, because it's a ThreadAbortException, the framework is automatically re-throwing it. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx) for more information.

The issue is that your PDF keyword searching code is (sometimes) taking longer than the specified HTTP execution timeout. I don't know what the default timeout is for Sharepoint, but you should be able to increase it.