# When uploading image file onto my server from my webpage I want to display message if the upload timesout VB.net code behind

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, file-upload, timeout

I check for file size and file extension already. But I still need to check if the upload process has timed out. If it does I want to display a message to the user that the upload timed out and they can try again later. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

```
    Dim success As Boolean = False
    Response.Write("*EIL*")
    Try
        If Not Context.Request.Files Is Nothing Then
            Dim fileCount As Int32 = Context.Request.Files.Count
            For fileLoop As Integer = 0 To fileCount - 1
                Dim file As HttpPostedFile = Context.Request.Files(fileLoop)
                Dim fileName As String
                If file.ContentLength > 20971520 Then
                    Response.Write("The upload failed because the file size is too large - 20MB is the limit.")
                Else
                    fileName = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(file.FileName)
                    Dim ext As String = fileName.Substring(fileName.Length - 4, 4).ToLower
                    If ext = ".jpg" Or ext = ".gif" Or ext = ".png" Or ext = ".bmp" Or ext = ".psd" Or ext = ".tif" Then
                        If InStr(fileName, "\") > 0 Then
                            Dim arr() As String = Split(fileName, "\")
                            fileName = arr(arr.Length - 1)
                        End If

                        file.SaveAs(String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ArtworkUploadPath"), fileName))

                        success = True
                    Else
                        Response.Write("The upload failed because the file was the wrong type.  Only files with the following extensions are allowed: .jpg, .gif, .png, .bmp, .psd, .tif")
                    End If
                End If
            Next
            If success Then Response.Write("Success")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** you can't.

**Longer answer:** When an upload times out, it's because the server decides your code is taking too long, kills your process, and then throws an exception. Thus your code is no longer running when the timeout occurs, so there's no way to display a message to the user.

You can log the timeout if you want, as explained in a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13769163/).

Ideally, you don't want to catch the timeout anyway, you want to fix your page so it doesn't time out. You can do this a couple ways:

- Change the value of `maxRequestLength` in your `system.web` to limit the allowed filesize, and [show an error page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/824298/) to the user when their upload exceeds it.
- Extend the timeout period by increasing the value of `executionTimeout` in your `system.web`, as in the [answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/230916/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Ok so can I catch it before it actually times out. Is there a way to set a specific time to display a message and exit out manually before it is forced by a timeout?

Comment: You can't cancel an HttpRequest on the server's end; you'd have to do it using client-side code (for example, make the 'submit' button `POST` to an iframe, start a counter when the user clicks the submit button, and change the `src` of the iframe after a certain amount of time has elapsed)